# Get All Photos from Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I need to get user uploaded and tagged photos from facebook account using graph API.

I tried following code but it's give nothing to me .

```
 GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                                        token,
                                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                                // Insert your code here

                                            Log.e("Hi "," "+response.getJSONObject().toString());

                                            }
                                        });

                              GraphRequest req = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(token, "me/photos",  callback);
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id, name");
            req.setParameters(parameters);
            req.executeAsync();
```

I have given following permission to facbook.

```
loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile","user_photos"));
```

Thanks

Comment: `parameters.putString("photos", "null");` -
 what is that supposed to achieve?
 Check the basic examples under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph - if you want to query specific fields/edges via a /me request, then you need to supply them under the parameter name `fields`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this API

```
json.FB_URL+json.PAGE_ID+"?fields=albums.limit(30)%7Bname%2Cid%2Cdescription%2Cpicture%7D&access_token="+json.ACCESS_TOKEN
```